# Spring Tools broke Maven in Eclipse

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have Eclipse  2019-12 (4.14.0) and installed STS 3.9.13.RELEASE from the marketplace. Since then I've not been able to import Maven projects (This is an issue.) Additinoally I don't have the ability to create a new Spring anything in it. I have uninstalled STS and reverted and I still can't get any options available for Maven. M2e is still installed and has been updated, reverted, and updated and all throughout there I'm not able to see anything.

Does anyone know how STS removed the support for Maven so I can recover my IDE?

Comment: Try to uninstall all m2e plugins and install them again from marketplace

Answer (score 0):

In case you really need the STS 3.9.x versions of the Spring Tools and not the Spring Tools 4 Edition, I would recommend to try the latest Eclipse release (2021-03) and install the latest STS3 components into it (instructions are here: https://github.com/spring-projects/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3).

That wiki page also provides ready-to-use distributions of the STS3 components with the latest Eclipse, which also contains m2e pre-installed.

But I would like to emphasize that the STS3 components have reached their EOL and receive only minimal maintenance updates, so I would strongly recommend to update to the Spring Tools 4.

In case you are missing an important feature of STS3 in the Spring Tools 4, please raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and explain what you would like to see in the Spring Tools 4 - and why. The "why" is interesting for us to understand your use case in more detail, so any details there would be highly welcome.